# Read Image File from HTTP POST Request in Flask and Convert it into a PIL Image

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-imaging-library

I have a simple flask server with a POST method to get an image from a user. Once getting the image, I need to convert that image to PIL image file and the rest of the process needs that PIL image file.

```
@app.route("/predict",methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    image=request.files['file']
    # convert this image to pil image
    .....
```

Is there any short method for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

image can be passed to Image.open(your_image) function.

```
pil_image = Image.open(image)
```